# How to trust a browser in PlayWright - Typescript ccode

Tags: playwright, playwright-typescript

I am trying to create a Playwright suite with typescript. But my code access client environment. Any borwser opened in that environment , gives a message to trust the browser. Only after clicking OK in that , I can proceed. Does Playwright support this feature ot trusting browsers? like selenium had "Options" for chorme.

Comment: What's the option you use in Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, u can pass browser arguments into the Projects or browser config inside playwright config file. something like this.

```
{
  name: "chrome",
  use: {
    ...devices["Desktop Chrome"],
    channel: "chrome",
    headless: false,
    launchOptions: {
      args: [
        "--disable-notifications",
        "--disable-gpu",
        "--ignore-certificate-errors",
        "--disable-extensions",
        "--no-sandbox",
        "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
      ],
    },
```

you can refer these,

List of common switches :
/master/chrome/common/chrome_switches.cc

List of headless switches :
/master/headless/app/headless_shell_switches.cc

To search other switches :
https://source.chromium.org/search?q=file:switches.cc&ss=chromium%2Fchromium%2Fsrc

List of preferences:
/master/chrome/common/pref_names.cc

or

https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/